# Calendar quarter-end immediately preceeding any given date

Tags: date, excel, vba

Essentially I may have any date and I want to get the proper quarter-end date for the previous quarter.

Three examples:

```
19/07/2013 -> 30/06/2013
30/06/2013 -> 31/03/2013
28/02/2013 -> 31/12/2012
```

In Excel VBA it seems using `DateAdd` to subtract a quarter just subtracts three months from the date, e.g. `19/07/2013` -> `19/04/2013`. This is no good for me.

- What do you think would be the best way of doing this?
- Perhaps extracting the month part and then comparing it to a list of the
  possible quarters?
- Or maybe having some sort of null date
  `01/01/2000` and then adding the number of quarters the given date
  shows as to this null date and then subtracting a day to get a
  previous quarter-end position (although this might cause problems
  when the date flips under a year to December 31)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider:

```
=IF(MOD(MONTH(A1),3)=0,EOMONTH(A1,-3),  
 IF(MOD(MONTH(A1),3)=1,EOMONTH(A1,-1), 
                       EOMONTH(A1,-2)))
```

Edit: There is a better answer in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the excel formula, certainly provides me with an idea for the logic to put into my sub. However 28/02/2013 returns 0? Is D1 a mistake?

Comment: Works a treat. The modulo is a good idea. Now to put this into vba code.

Comment: You could put the MOD logic into a single EOMONTH function, i.e. `=EOMONTH(A1,MOD(-MONTH(A1),3)-3)`....or this version might be more transparent `=DATE(YEAR(A1),FLOOR(MONTH(A1)-1,3)+1,0)`

Comment: That's awesome Barry. What beautifully concise logic!

Comment: @barryhoudini gave the formula for the universal quater jan-mar,apr-jun...
what if i want to give my own quarter list say quarter ends in NOV?